# A person who disowns all the credit

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a testimonial. I am looking out for a word, preferably a noun, that means "the quality of disowning all the credits after success." Alternatively, I am okay with adjectives too. Words like humility and modesty do ring in my mind, but I am not sure if there is a more appropriate word.

Comment: You should add a sentence where this term would be used, something like *"Despite the phenomenal success,  blah, blah,  ____ blah, blah."* The blank space is where the word would be placed. However, it seems a bit odd a person who negates any form of praise or recognition in their success.

Comment: "self-abnegation" comes to mind, but I would need a little more context...

Answer (score 1):

As an adjective, a possibility is [**self-deprecatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-deprecatory):

> expressing disparagement or undervaluation of oneself

In particular the *undervaluation* component, not necessarily *disparagement*.